# Minimising an expression - involving polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I found this one on a forum but it has been unanswered from long there. I am curious to know if there is a solution to this problem. Here it is:

Let n be a positive integer. Determine the smallest possible value of
$$|p(1)|^2+|p(2)|^2 + .........+ |p(n+3)|^2$$
over all monic polynomials p with degree n.

---

I don't have much idea about the problem. I can go about by assuming $p$ to be some monic polynomial and find $p(1)$, $p(2)$.... in terms of the coefficients but I don't think that is going to help. This is some inequality related problem, I guess.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

PS: Can somebody please check if I have added the proper tags? I am not sure where this kind of problem should belong.

Comment: No, there is nothing else mentioned. :(

Comment: Can you link a source for the problem?

Comment: Here it is: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=753528

Comment: @T.Bongers: Any ideas? I am still stuck on this one.

Comment: @T.Bongers: the polynomials must be monic, so the expression can't be arbitrarily small (at least not a priori).

Comment: For $n=0,1,2,3$ the minimal values of the expression are $3$, $5$, $14$, $\frac{324}5$, achieved by the unique polynomials $1$, $x-\frac52$, $x^2-6x+7$, and $x^3-\frac{21}2x^2+\frac{317}{10}x-\frac{126}5$. For any fixed $n$ it's just a linear algebra problem (as per Ray Vickson's answer on physicsforums), but I don't immediately see a way to solve it for all $n$ at once.

Comment: I am not seeing how you got those polynomials for specific cases. Can you please explain? Also, I am not aware of linear algebra. Is their a method which doesn't use that?

Answer (score 3):

Let us define, for two polynomials $p,q$ of degree at most $n$, the bilinear form 
$$(p,q):=\sum_{k=1}^{n+3}p(k)q(k)$$

Observe that this bilinear form is a scalar product since $||p||^2:=(p,p)$ is positive definite. $$||p||^2=0\implies p=0$$

We need to find the closest point of $A:=\{p:\ p\text{ is monic}\}$ to the origin. Equivalently we can find the distance of $-x^n$ to the linear subspace $B:=A-\{x^n\}=\{p:\ \text{deg}(p)<n\}$.

We know that the polynomial providing the minimum distance is the orthogonal projection $P(x)$ of $v:=v(x):=-x^n$ onto $B$. If $v_1(x),v_2(x),...,v_n(x)$ is an orthonormal basis of $B$ then

> $$P(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-x^n,v_k)v_k(x)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \text{(1)}$$

To obtain an orthonormal basis of $B$ we can apply [Gram-Schmidt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to a basis of $B$, say $1,x,..,x^{n-1}$.

To make the computation let us denote $$s_m:=\sum_{k=1}^{n+3}k^m$$
We see that $$(x^r,x^s)=s_{r+s}$$

We can write the result of Gram-Schmidt in determinant form as 
$$v_i(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{j-i}D_j}}\text{det}\begin{bmatrix}s_0&s_1&...&s_{j-1}\\s_1&s_2&...&s_j\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\s_{j-2}&s_{j-1}&...&s_{2j-3}\\1&x&...&x^{j-1}\end{bmatrix}$$
where
$$D_j=\text{det}\begin{bmatrix}s_0&s_1&...&s_{j-1}\\s_1&s_2&...&s_j\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\s_{j-1}&s_{j}&...&s_{2j-2}\end{bmatrix}$$

We can now compute 
$$(-x^n,v_k(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{j-i}D_j}}\text{det}\begin{bmatrix}s_0&s_1&...&s_{j-1}\\s_1&s_2&...&s_j\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\s_{j-2}&s_{j-1}&...&s_{2j-3}\\-s_n&-s_{n+1}&...&-s_{n+j-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

So, the polynomial that minimizes the sum is

> $$x^n+P(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

Cross-posted and answered 
[on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210823). 
The formula is $(2n+1)(2n+3) n!^4 / (2n)!$.
See my answer to 
[MO_210823](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210823) for the proof.

In general the minimum value of $\sum_{i=1}^{n+k+1} p(i)^2$
over monic polynomials $p$ of degree $n$ is
$$
\frac{n!^4}{(2n)!} {2n+1+k \, \choose k},
$$
and the minimizing $p$ is proportional to a
[Hahn polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_polynomials)
$Q_n$ evaluated at $x-1$ (with $\alpha=\beta=0$ and $N = n+k+1$).